# What type of marker is [sic] in a text? It is not an editor's mark, so what is it?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

The marker "[sic]" is used in a published work to show that a word-usage or spelling is recognised by the author to be incorrect or unconventional.

On the other hand, editors' marks (proofreading symbols) are made *before* publication, they show what must be changed for the work to be acceptable. They do not appear in the finished work.

[Common Proofreading Symbols](http://www.ccc.commnet.edu/writing/symbols.htm)

**Question**

So what kind of a thing is "[sic]"? Is it unique or are there other marks that appear in a finished text and perform a related function?

Comment: It depends on how you use it. That marker has several functions.

Comment: @Robusto - Okay, thanks, but what are these functions *called*? What is the term that describes the class of sic-like markers?

Comment: I'm tempted to call it an *editorial note*; and there are an unbounded number of such possible insertions. Anywhere an author does what the Chicago Manual of Style calls "quiet copy-editing", inserting a bracketed word not found in the original quote, that serves the same function (and often obviates the need for a *sic*). They may even use square-brackets to do something as trivial as capitalize a word so they can start a quote in the middle of a sentence. Anyway, other common editorial notes which have fixed meanings include *recte* (*sic*'s brother), and *read:*.

Comment: It's inserted either by an editor, or by an author when quoting. The quote must be exact, and the [sic] goes after some solecism or crazy statement in the quotation. Basically, it means 'Yes, they really said that; your eyes do not deceive you. It's no fault of mine, though'. I have known academics who believed an exclamation point was part of the convention; i.e, [_sic!_].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Chicago Manual of Style* uses the term "editorial interpolations" for these bracketed items that appear inside quotations, for which there are four reasons beside the error flag "*sic*":

1. To remove an ambiguity:

> "The chair recognized Mr Johnson **[of Tennessee]**."

2. To supply missing letters:

> The poet in question is e**[dward]** e**[stlin]** cummings.

3. To give an appositive technical term in a foreign language:

   > He claimed citizenship by right of his territorial birth **[*lex solis*]**.
4. To express "contempt, scorn, or doubt" with an exclamation mark or question mark, although these are "usually best left unmade."

> The candidate claimed he had the best **[!]** interest of the country at
>   heart.

Comment: Nice research and helpful examples.  I'm jealous!

Comment: Just to be clear, these are the reasons the *CMS* finds acceptable.  (Anyone can pretend to be an expert with a thoughtful look on his face and a copy of the *CMS* in one hand.)  The examples are mine, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are three elements here:  the word ‘sic’; the fact that it is typically italicised; and the square brackets.  This usage generally relates to the presentation of quotations.

The word ‘sic’ is Latin for ‘thus’.  In this context it is used by an author to indicate that an apparent error (a misspelling, for example) *is* ‘correct’, in the sense that it was present in the text that is being quoted.  As has been said, it means something along the lines of, ‘Yes, *you* know that that’s wrong, and so do *I*, but *that* is what they actually *wrote*, and it would be wrong of me to pretend they had written something that you and I would prefer.’

The word is usually italicised because that is the convention for words from other languages—in this case Latin, which is foreign to *all* current languages.  (Incidentally, that also tends to help in distinguishing the editorial comment from the surrounding quotation.)

Square brackets will be used with ‘sic’ (as with other uses, e.g. those quoted here from *The Chicago Manual of Style*) to show that this is the voice or action of the *present* author, *within* a quotation from someone else.  (To the best of my knowledge, by the way, there is no easy editorial fix for this kind of thing clashing with a quotation that already contains square brackets, other than to include a slightly confusing note ‘[Square brackets in original.]’)

The following is an example from my own Ph.D thesis, where I am quoting Michele Pierson’s (ill-informed and misleading, as it happens) comments on Joanna Russ’s discussion of the marketing of science fiction:

> This is Russ’s point, that the marketing of it as entertainment heads
>   criticism off at the path [*sic*] by appealing to the (largely
>   manufactured) consensus that only spoilsports engage in it.

Pierson is certainly thinking of the expression ‘to head [something or someone] off at the *pass*’.  (I believe that this derives from Westerns.  It has become a common metaphor for intercepting someone’s route or plan at a predictable point.)  She and her editor, however, have made the reasonably common error of giving ‘path’ instead of ‘pass’.  It is pretty obvious what the text should say *but doesn’t*.  It would be academically fraudulent of me, however, to change it.

There are two acceptable options for me here.  One would be to replace the word ‘path’ with ‘[pass]’, using square brackets to show that this is *my* insertion, and that I stand by the sense of it.  The down-side of this is that you cannot see precisely what I have replaced:  it could be a single word, or a whole phrase, or the end of one sentence and the beginning of another (possibly with several in between).  If you could see the original, you might disagree with my amendment/gloss.  As it is, you have no way of judging.

The option I have therefore chosen is to give the text precisely as it was published, but to reassure *my* reader that I do know about the error, and have faithfully carried it over from the original.  Therefore I use the convention of saying ‘[*sic*]’, i.e. ‘It really was given thus in the original.’  This is in italics because the word is Latin, and also in square brackets (which are *not* italicised) to show that this is my voice and not Pierson’s.  In this very quote, you can see that that also distinguishes it from her own use of conventional brackets for her own aside.